# Are there any plans for Microsoft to support testing frameworks other than MSTest?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, mbunit

It seems like you should be able to configure your preferred unit testing framework as a plugin to Visual Studio/Team system like you can with SourceControl providers. Is anyone aware of an effort within microsoft to allow for swapping out MStest for nUnit, mbUnit or others.  Obviosly nothing prevents me from using these other frameworks but they aren't integrated into the IDE.

Comment: Why would that be Microsoft's job?

Comment: Get ReSharper                 .

Comment: I use TestDriven.NET and ReSharper, which integrate into the IDE and let you run tests.  But they don't plug into the "Test" menu that allows you to generate tests, you can only generate MSTests with that feature of the IDE, which is what I was asking about

Comment: You might want to post this question on social.msdn.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is coming to [Visual Studio 11](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/post/Unit-Testing-with-MSTest-xUnit-and-NUnit-in-the-VS11-Developer-Preview.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

If you have a look at [TestDriven.NET](http://testdriven.net) and [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org), they both have test runners that integrate to the IDE and allow the use of other testing frameworks.

If you are adverse to spending a little this is just on of the many benefits of [ReSharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper). (r#)

Not sure MS would want to encourage us to use another one unfortunately.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: @Dan Elliott: When creating an ASP.NET MVC project they allow selection of an alternative test framework so they're not *totally* against it.

Comment: Brad Wilson (the creator of xUnit is) on the ASP.NET MVC team; I think these facts may be related ;)

Comment: @Alex, I'll have to look into MVC's method of selecting an alternative test framework. How is that accomplished?

Comment: Found it, this is a start. "The Test Framework wizard will allow the developer to choose from a list of available unit testing frameworks but is pluggable to allow for additional testing frameworks to be added."

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does provide the concept of custom test adapters that would allow custom test frameworks to execute under the MSTest platform.  That is, tests for those frameworks would appear in the Test List Editor, etc.

The developers of the custom frameworks would have to develop a VSPackage that would find and provide tests to MSTest.  Unfortunately, there's a lot of work involved.

TestDriven.NET, Resharper (and several others) provide their own VSPackage to provide their own Tool Window, but do not integrate directly with MSTest.